# subtract rows one by one from numpy array

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, vectorization

I have a 2D numpy array, A.

I want to subtract each rows, one by one, from A, and store the row-wise absolute sum in an array.

Is there a way to carry out the operation without using the for loop ?  Below is the code with for loop.

```
import numpy as np
A = np.random.randint(5,size=(8,9))
b = np.zeros(A.shape[1]);
for i in xrange(A.shape[0]):
    b = b + np.sum(np.absolute(A - A[i,:]), axis=0)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`broadcasting`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/user/basics.broadcasting.html) -

```
(np.abs(A[:,None,:] - A)).sum(axis=(0,1))
```

Steps :

(1) Keeping the last axis aligned get two versions of `A` :

```
Input1 (A[:,None,:])    :  M x 1 x N
Input2 (A)              :      M x N
```

Get the absolution differences between these two inputs resulting in a `3D` array.

(2) Sum along the first two axes for final output.